# Can I return response before task is done?

Tags: python-3.x, api, asynchronous, flask, response

I have simple flask api. Part of the code is bellow.

```py
@app.route("/newTask")
def task():
    new_task = Task()
    asyncio.run(new_task.do_something())  # something like this?
    return f'New task with number {new_task.id} created'


@app.route("/tasks")
def task_status():
    response = {task.id: task.status for task in TasksTable}
    return jsonify(response)
```

When I make a request to `http://something/newTask` I would like to immediately see response "New task with number X created".
And then at `/tasks` endpoint observe this:

```
{
  "1": "initialized", 
}
```

After refresh this:

```
{
  "1": "in progress", 
}
```

And after some time this:

```
{
  "1": "done", 
}
```

Is it possible without celery? Maybe using asyncio?

Comment: Nevermind, I solve this with threading.

Comment: can you show ur solution, please?